# Set a tag on slots/hotbars

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to know if you can do so that all the slots in the players inventory gets a specifc tag. etc if something is in slot 8 it will get a name. Or if something is in the hotbar 2 it will kill the player.

Comment: Not without modding.

Comment: Please don't change the question to something completely different. The answers don't fit anymore if you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No.

That's not possible in Vanilla Minecraft. And I also highly doubt that there is a mod that does it.

You should instead ask about the thing you really want to do with that tag. It's much more likely that you'll get an answer to that.